# Inserting values into a string for a directory path wont work

Tags: python, directory, insert

im trying to save a game state for a board game, but when I try to insert "player_1" and "player_2" (both global variables) into the string it simply doesnt insert them and just create a directory called " - "

[image: here is the file it creates]

I've tried doing

```
global player_1,player_2
```

at the top of the function but nothing is working.

Below is the code for the function.

```
def save_game(board,IsPlaying):
    path = f"games/{player_1} - {player_2}"
    print (path)
    os.mkdir(path)
    
    f = open(f"{path}/Player1.txt", "w")
    f.write(player_1)
    f.close

    f = open(f"{path}/Player2.txt", "w")
    f.write(player_2)
    f.close

    f = open("{path}/board {} - {}.txt"(player_1,player_2), "w")
    BoardToSave = list()
    for c in board:
        BoardToSave.append(c)
    f.write(BoardToSave)
    f.close
```

Board is also stored as a Numpy array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as im completely stuck.

Comment: Are you sure they have a value?

Comment: Yeah the function cant be called without them having values

Comment: We'd need to see more code to see that.  I've told myself that before and been wrong.  I always start with Python works more consistently than I do

Comment: I made a rudementary fix by creating a list and placing them in in a previous function and it seems to work. Sorry for wasting your time

Answer (score 0):

I just created a list called players and placed player_1 and player_2 inside it then passed that list into the function